# How to detect whether the device is connected to the internet on a mobile app?

Tags: jquery, mobile-application, appframework

I am building a mobile application using App Framework and Jquery. It is expected to work on Android and IOS.

I would like to alert the user with an alert message when they are not connected to the internet via WiFi or Mobile data. What is the best and accurate way to do it ?

Comment: You're supposed to indicate what you have done so far and if possible show some code. Also "best and accurate" is opinion-based and not the kind of questions that is asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: People should be more experienced to have their own opinions. And Novice like me do use such words to learn something good. Yes, I haven't tried anything as I don't know what to do. I am new and thanks for letting me know this is not the place for novice to learn. Will delete the question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

call this in your javascript:

```
window.navigator.onLine
```

this will return true if you're connected and false if not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please explain this with a function or a JSFiddle to be more helpful ? and also confirm if this is gonna work on a mobile app

Answer (score 0):

If you are building hybrid app then you can use the Cordova connection api to detect which type of connection the device is on: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

Comment: I won't use PhoneGap here, as I will be using Intel XDK to build the app.

Comment: intel XDK build supports Cordova/PhoneGap APIs too. So you can use the Cordova connection API. Or if you want to use Intel XDK API, then there is a similar connection API: http://www.html5dev-software.intel.com/documentation/jsAPI/device/updateConnection/index.html

Comment: Thanks Krisrak. How can I use this function, could you pls show me a demo ?

Comment: here is sample code for xdk connection api: https://github.com/krisrak/html5-kitchensink-cordova-xdk-af/blob/master/index.html#L3715

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.connection.update",function()
{
 alert(intel.xdk.device.connection);
},false);

intel.xdk.device.updateConnection();
```

Plz consult the referrend links that will provide you good idea about the connection events.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493063
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493102